# S&P500 (^GSPC) query via query.yahooapis.com occasionally got "Name":null result

Tags: yql

S&P500 (^GSPC) query via query.yahooapis.com occasionally got "Name":null result in the JSON output. Other time it yield "Name":"S&P 500".

Suspect this is an API bug related to special character "&" in the Name field, any idea?

Query:
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22^GSPC%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

Result (sometime Name is null):
... "results":{"quote":{"symbol":"^GSPC", ..., "Name":null, ...